# Can I install programs on a Mac without admin rights?

Tags: macos, installation, administrator

I have a company laptop, a MacBook. I just need to know if I can install any program without having admin rights or an admin password?

Comment: I think you need to ask your company IT dept.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/30359/how-do-i-reset-my-mac-os-x-password-without-an-install-disk

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it is a drag & drop installation you can drag it to the Applications folder within your user folder, or anywhere within your user folder for that matter. If it uses Apple's Installer you will need an admin name & password. You may or may not be able to get around that by right clicking on the installer package, select "Show Package Contents" and drag & drop the app from there.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is not a "Mac" answer, it's a general Unix answer which "might" work for certain programs under OS/X:

If it's open-source, just compile the source under your own user directory in Terminal. If "make install" fails due to lack of administrative privilege, simply run the executable from its location.

Answer (score -5):

Start you mac up and hold control and then this dual core will pop up jut sign in to your automatic account know as the mac's admin and not owner's admin. Their will be another user called admin that has no password like a pc. MAC have a windows xp start up so it will work.

Comment: you know how old that question is?

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan I don't see why that would matter. The answer is just wrong, that's all.