# How to use ophcrack for Mac password?

Tags: linux, macos, passwords, operating-systems

I have used ophcrack before for Windows as it uses the Rainbow tables supplied on their website.

Are there similar tables that can be loaded into ophcrack for OS X / MacOS?

Comment: ophcrack is for Windows only, as evidenced at http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/ .  You might have better luck searching "forgot my MacOS password", for Answers like this : https://superuser.com/questions/30359/how-do-i-reset-my-mac-os-x-password-without-an-install-disk

Comment: macOS uses salted password hashes (mostly, depending on where the account came from); as a result, rainbow tables cannot be used on macOS password hashes. You'd have to use a standard brute-forcer, like [John the Ripper](https://www.openwall.com/john/), [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/), or [DaveGrohl](https://github.com/octomagon/davegrohl). Any of will be slow (since macOS intentionally uses a slow hash) and hence unable to crack complex passwords in reasonable amounts of time.

Comment: Less chance still if it has a T2 chip - https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208198